# Pycharm: Enforce Pep8 warnings in pycharm

Tags: pycharm, pep8

My pycharm is showing pep8 warning - line is longer than 79 characters in below line:

```
global tops_per_lane_map_cache, target_group_usage_map_cache, ppv2_enabled_target_group_usage_map_cache, min_tops_per_lane_map_cache, lbs_per_lane_map_cache
```

When i reformat code using Code>ReformatCode in pycharm. It didnt split the line.
How can i format my lines in pycharm?

Comment: Seems to have something to do with the "global" keyword. If you replace (for example) "global" by "import", pycharm correctly wraps the line.